# Auto load classes by class name like Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller, autoload, zend-autoloader

How can I auto load my framework controllers and models by their class name like the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) does?

Zend Framework auto loads classes like so:

`new Application_Controller_Index();`

meaning that controller class is located at `application/controllers/IndexController.php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not to have a look in the source code ? http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Loader.php

just in case, probably the simplest way:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($classname){
    include str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $classname) . '.php';
});
```

Comment: This seems to be the best method of doing this, so I am accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use function __autoload and you should be all set.

There are really good examples on the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Also please note that the __autoload might be deprecated soon. To go around that, use the [spl_autoload_register()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) as the manual says.

Comment: I understand I need to use an auto load function, I'm asking how Zend has it set up so they don't need to specify a directory, just include the class name which is then parsed into a directory to find the class.

Comment: To use the format you specified above, you have to [explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the class name in to bits and get the path from the array.